# Baking Textures Results in Completely Black Texture

Tags: materials, texture-baking

I'm following Dikko's tutorial for baking UDIM textures (https://youtu.be/G7ZNLJMEn0Y) because I want to bake a multiresolution sculpt's details, with the use of a material, into a diffuse texture for UDIMs, but every bake attempt results in a completely black image. I am using Blender 2.9.0, using 4 levels of subdivision for the multiresolution, 16 samples in Cycles for rendering, world light for lighting, I recalculated normals, selected the appropriate UV map and selected the UV input node + image texture node in the material editor to which I want to bake. Why does Blender still bake black textures like the one on the upper left?

[image: Viewport render and the baked image on the left]

Comment: A little bit late, but make sure you have *Subsurface Scattering* of the *Principled BSDF* node set to `0` and *Metallic* to `0`. Otherwise, the baked texture will be (almost) black. Related question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/251964/107598