# Texture Bake is Always a Black Square Even though I Unwrapped Everything I Need to Unwrap for Game Engine

Tags: texturing, game-engine, texture-baking, baking

I unwrapped this object. Here is an image of the unwrap.
[image]

I tried to bake the diffuse and I set everything exactly the way it should be (aka Cycles, CPU, indirect and direct lighting off) but I just get a black square.

This is the image mid bake.
[image]

This is the finished bake. As you can see it is blank.
[image]

Why is it blank? What am I doing wrong?

P.S. Here is the Blender File:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ft4Qhh4tybpUjZ2GJYMBrWWFhGguNm55/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You have set *Metallic* to 1. This causes the bake to be black. Have a  look here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/233296/107598

Comment: @Blunder This fixed it! Thank you so much! If you want to make this an answer I will check it as accepted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have set *Metallic* of the *Principled BSDF* node to 1. This causes the bake of the *Diffuse* color to be black.

For baking set *Metallic* and (*Subsurface* scattering) to 0. After baking, you can restore the *Metallic* value again.

(With the bake type *Emit* you can bake a Metallic map if needed.)