# Problems with texture baking

Tags: modeling

[image]

I can't bake the texture, the scan is there, the normals are fine, but the output is a black texture

Comment: Hello. Your node setup is not fully visible in the screenshot. First, I would set the *Metallic* value of the *Principled BSDF* to 0 if you want to bake the diffuse color (or any other than metal) and make sure that also *Subsurface Scattering* is turned off (0). Possible duplicate question => https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/251964/107598

Comment: After I removed Metallic, everything really worked out, thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm glad to hear it worked :-)