# Why can't I bake my colors on my image texture?

Tags: texture-baking, baking

So I am trying to export my crown model to SFM the problem is I can't bake my colors on the image texture here. Every time I try it ends up in this unfinished purple state (picture 1) my question is what did I do wrong? Can you please explain that to me?

what I did was uv unwrap the model, go to shader mode, set the baking setting to Cycle, deactivate the direct and indirect lights and set the bake type to to combined and click both the model and image texture with a new texture.
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Texture Bake is Always a Black Square Even though I Unwrapped Everything I Need to Unwrap for Game Engine](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/251964/texture-bake-is-always-a-black-square-even-though-i-unwrapped-everything-i-need)

Comment: You have set Mettallic to 1 this results in the black areas.

Comment: ok so you were right it was the metalic effect thank you for that. but 1 problem is now the colors look off without the metalic effect is there a way to export it as well ?